# Write a custom linter for ale to consume the output of command line utility

Tags: vimscript, plugin-ale

I am trying to write an [ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) linter for the [norminette](https://github.com/42School/norminette) program. How can I make it work ?

It's a program that checks if C source code files follow the coding norm of the 42 school
network and it would save me time to be able to have it integrate tis he ale plugin.

I am not well versed in VimL and this is what I was able to come up with, putting this in the `~/.vim/plugged/ale/ale_linters/c` directory :

```
call ale#Set('c_norminette_executable', 'norminette')
call ale#Set('c_norminette_options', '')

function! ale_linters#c#norminette#GetExecutable(buffer) abort
    return ale#Var(a:buffer, 'c_norminette_executable')
endfunction

function! ale_linters#c#norminette#GetCommand(buffer) abort
    return ale#Escape(ale_linters#c#norminette#GetExecutable(a:buffer))
    \   . ale#Var(a:buffer, 'c_norminette_options')
    \   . ' %t'
endfunction

function! ale_linters#c#norminette#Opscript(buffer, lines) abort
    " Look for lines like the following.
    "
    "ft_lstsize.c: Error!
    "Error: SPACE_REPLACE_TAB    (line:  17, col:  11): Found space when expecting tab
    "ft_calloc.c: OK!
    "ft_memcpy.c: Error!
    "Error: SPACE_AFTER_KW       (line:  22, col:  19): Missing space after keyword
    "test.c: Error!
    "Error: SPACE_BEFORE_FUNC    (line:   6, col:   4): space before function name
    "Error: WRONG_SCOPE_COMMENT  (line:  12, col:   9): Comment is invalid in this scope
    "ft_isalnum.c: OK!

    let l:pattern = '\(^\(\h\+\.[ch]\): \(\w\+\)!$\|^Error: \h\+\s\+(line:\s\+\(\d\+\),\s\+col:\s\+\(\d\+\)):\s\+\(.*\)\)'
    let l:output = []
    let l:curr_file = ''

    for l:match in ale#util#GetMatches(a:lines, l:pattern)
        if l:match[2] == 'OK'
            continue
        elseif l:match[2] == "Error"
            let l:curr_file = l:match[1]
        " if ale#path#IsBufferPath(a:buffer, l:curr_file) && l:match[1] == "Error"
        else
            call add(l:output, {
            \   'lnum': str2nr(l:match[1]),
            \   'col': str2nr(l:match[2]),
            \   'type': 'E',
            \   'text': l:match[3],
            \})
        endif
    endfor

    return l:output
endfunction

call ale#linter#Define('c', {
\   'name': 'norminette',
\   'output_stream': 'both',
\   'executable': function('ale_linters#c#norminette#GetExecutable'),
\   'command': function('ale_linters#c#norminette#GetCommand'),
\   'callback': 'ale_linters#c#norminette#Opscript',
\})
```

There's an comment in the function that shows what the `norminette` ouputs to the terminal.
I know that my pattern works because I tested it on the output thanks to the `set incsearch` parameter.

```
" Given a single line, or a List of lines, and a single pattern, or a List      
" of patterns, return all of the matches for the lines(s) from the given        
" patterns, using matchlist().                                                  
"                                                                               
" Only the first pattern which matches a line will be returned.                 
function! ale#util#GetMatches(lines, patterns) abort                            
    let l:matches = []                                                          
    let l:lines = type(a:lines) is v:t_list ? a:lines : [a:lines]               
    let l:patterns = type(a:patterns) is v:t_list ? a:patterns : [a:patterns]   
                                                                                
    for l:line in l:lines                                                       
        for l:pattern in l:patterns                                             
            let l:match = matchlist(l:line, l:pattern)                          
                                                                                
            if !empty(l:match)                                                  
                call add(l:matches, l:match)                                    
                break                                                           
            endif                                                               
        endfor                                                                  
    endfor                                                                      
                                                                                
    return l:matches                                                            
endfunction
```

If you want to see it for yourself and install it, it as easy as running:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
python3 -m pip install norminette
```

Here is the ale_linters#c#norminette#GetExecutable function :

```
" Given a single line, or a List of lines, and a single pattern, or a List      
" of patterns, return all of the matches for the lines(s) from the given        
" patterns, using matchlist().                                                  
"                                                                               
" Only the first pattern which matches a line will be returned.                 
function! ale#util#GetMatches(lines, patterns) abort                            
    let l:matches = []                                                          
    let l:lines = type(a:lines) is v:t_list ? a:lines : [a:lines]               
    let l:patterns = type(a:patterns) is v:t_list ? a:patterns : [a:patterns]   
                                                                                
    for l:line in l:lines                                                       
        for l:pattern in l:patterns                                             
            let l:match = matchlist(l:line, l:pattern)                          
                                                                                
            if !empty(l:match)                                                  
                call add(l:matches, l:match)                                    
                break                                                           
            endif                                                               
        endfor                                                                  
    endfor                                                                      
                                                                                
    return l:matches                                                            
endfunction
```

I am sorry to ask such a specific question. I've given it my best and I've tried other channels for help but I have not found any. This is my last attempt before I actually buy a book to learn how to program in Vimscript :)
(I am getting quite good at vimregex though)

Comment: Apparently there is no syntax highlighting for viml on SO. Sorry about that.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Is something not working? Fwiw, I would approach this by scanning for lines matching `filename: Error` and then looking at the lines after that for the messages and such (nested loops, two patterns instead of one).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Edited to ask my "question" that is how do I make it work ?
Thanks for your advice, I'll see if I can go further with it.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Questions should stay questions, even if you now have answers for them. Please self-answer instead—this is encouraged here! I'm glad you figured it out; I was coming back to write an answer when I saw you had solved your problem. (If you need the content of the old edit, you can get it in the edit history.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble So I did. Thanks for doing the work of maintaining this place in a good shape. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the file in question with commented lines that contain useful tips to create your own ale linter. I hope it can provide a useful template for others to use :

```
" Description: norminette linter for C files.
"
" Get the norminette with :
"
" python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
" python3 -m pip install norminette
"
" or at : https://github.com/42School/norminette

call ale#Set('c_norminette_executable', 'norminette')
call ale#Set('c_norminette_options', '')

function! ale_linters#c#norminette#GetExecutable(buffer) abort
    return ale#Var(a:buffer, 'c_norminette_executable')
endfunction

function! ale_linters#c#norminette#GetCommand(buffer) abort
    return ale#Escape(ale_linters#c#norminette#GetExecutable(a:buffer))
    \   . ale#Var(a:buffer, 'c_norminette_options')
    \   . ' %t'
endfunction

function! ale_linters#c#norminette#Opscript(buffer, lines) abort
    " Look for lines like the following.
    " :set incsearch to test your patterns in real-time !
    "
    "ft_lstsize.c: Error!
    "Error: SPACE_REPLACE_TAB    (line:  17, col:  11): Found space when expecting tab
    "ft_calloc.c: OK!
    "ft_memcpy.c: Error!
    "Error: SPACE_AFTER_KW       (line:  22, col:  19): Missing space after keyword
    "test.c: Error!
    "Error: SPACE_BEFORE_FUNC    (line:   6, col:   4): space before function name
    "Error: WRONG_SCOPE_COMMENT  (line:  12, col:   9): Comment is invalid in this scope
    "ft_isalnum.c: OK!

    let l:pattern = '\(^\(\h\+\.[ch]\): \(\w\+\)!$\|^Error: \h\+\s\+(line:\s\+\(\d\+\),\s\+col:\s\+\(\d\+\)):\s\+\(.*\)\)'
    let l:output = []
    let l:curr_file = ''
    
    "A good tip to check what is at each index of l:match is to run inside Vim :
    ":let pattern='\(^\(\h\+\.[ch]\): \(\w\+\)!$\|^Error: \h\+\s\+(line:\s\+\(\d\+\),\s\+col:\s\+\(\d\+\)):\s\+\(.*\)\)'
    ":echo ale#util#GetMatches(['ft_lstsize.c: Error!'], pattern)
    "                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    "                          Replace with each line you want to  match
    "               

    for l:match in ale#util#GetMatches(a:lines, l:pattern)
        if l:match[3] == 'OK'
            continue
        elseif l:match[3] == "Error"
            let l:curr_file = l:match[2]
        else
            call add(l:output, {
            \   'filename': l:curr_file,
            \   'lnum': str2nr(l:match[4]),
            \  'col': str2nr(l:match[5]),
            \   'type': 'W',
            \   'text': "Norminette : " . l:match[6],
            \})
        endif
    endfor

    return l:output
endfunction

call ale#linter#Define('c', {
\   'name': 'norminette',
\   'output_stream': 'both',
\   'executable': function('ale_linters#c#norminette#GetExecutable'),
\   'command': function('ale_linters#c#norminette#GetCommand'),
\   'callback': 'ale_linters#c#norminette#Opscript',
\})
```